# Cannot post non-english (arabic/persian) letters as a Youtube movie description when uploading a video to Youtube via PHP

Tags: php, video, youtube

I am uploading video from my website via PHP to Youtube. When the description is in Persian/Arabic languages, I get this error

> HTTP 400: youtube.video, The request metadata specifies an invalid video description

But for English letters, there is no problem.

I follow the way given in [Codexworld](http://www.codexworld.com/upload-video-to-youtube-using-php/). In `youtube_upload.php` file every thing is the same, but the following code which I added at the top of the file

```
<?php
require_once './config.php';
?>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
$videoTitle = $_POST['title'];
$videoDesc =  $_POST['description'];
$fileType = "video/mp4";
$fileName = $_POST['filename'];
$nid= $_POST['nid'];
$videoFilePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/sites/THEME_NAME/files/video_file/".$fileName;
```

How can I insert Non-Enlish letters as description?

Comment: Should be able to set different language title and description. Can you please provide the values you are sending for title and description

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam There is no problem with the Title, But the error is reported for any description. for example I post, "این یک تست است".

Comment: I able to upload with the description you gave, not sure why you are getting an error